# How do we get to the equation $X+UY=c\left ( \frac{t+1}{t-1}\right )^m=c(T+U)^m$ ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, pell-type-equations

I am reading the proof of the following lemma but I got stuck at some points...

Let $R$ be any integral domain of characteristic zero.

We consider the Pell equation $$X^2-(T^2-1)Y^2=1 \tag 1$$ over $R[T]$.

Let $U$ be an element in the algebraic closure of $R[T]$ satisfying $$U^2=T^2-1 \tag 2$$

Define two sequences $X_n, Y_n, n=0, 1, 2, \dots$, of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[T]$, by setting $$X_n+UY_n=(T+U)^n\tag 3$$

**Lemma.**

The solutions of $(1)$ in $R[T]$ are given precisely by $$X=\pm X_n, Y=\pm Y_n, n=0, 1, 2, \dots$$

*Proof.*

$(1)$ is equivalent too $$(X-UY)(X+UY)=1 \tag 4$$

From $(3)$ and $(2)$ follows $$X_n-UY_n=(T-U)^n=(T+U)^{-n}$$

Hence the $X_n, Y_n$ are solutions of $(1)$.

Conversely, suppose $X$ and $Y$ in $R[T]$ satisfy $(1)$.

Let us parametrise the curve $(2)$ by $$T=\frac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}\ \ ,\ \  U=\frac{2t}{t^2-1}$$

The rational functions $X+UY$ and $X-UY$ in $t$ have poles only at $t=\pm 1$.

Moreover $(4)$ implies they have zeroes only at $t=\pm 1$.

Hence $$X+UY=c\left ( \frac{t+1}{t-1}\right )^m=c(T+U)^m, c \in R, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Thus also $X-UY=c(T-U)^m$.

But substistuting this in $(4)$ gives $c^2=1$, which proves the lemma by $(3)$.

$$$$

Could you explain to me the following part of the proof?

> Moreover $(4)$ implies they have zeroes only at $t=\pm 1$.
>
> Hence $$X+UY=c\left ( \frac{t+1}{t-1}\right )^m=c(T+U)^m, c \in R, m
> > \in \mathbb{Z}$$
>
> Thus also $X-UY=c(T-U)^m$.
>
> But substistuting this in $(4)$ gives $c^2=1$, which proves the lemma
>   by $(3)$.

Why do we have from the relation $(4)$ that the functions $X+UY$ and $X-UY$ have zeroes only at $t=\pm 1$ ?

How do we get to the equation $X+UY=c\left ( \frac{t+1}{t-1}\right )^m=c(T+U)^m$ ? How does $c$ appear?

Comment: what book is this in?

Comment: It is from this paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1978-242-00/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work on this some more. I suggest pretending the ring is the integers, to begin with.

I can offer a concrete version. The $(X,Y)$ solutions are
$$ (1,0),  $$
$$ (T,1),  $$
$$ (2 T^2 - 1,2T),  $$
$$ (4 T^3 -3T,4 T^2 - 1),  $$
as well as negating the $X$ part or the $Y$ part or both.

The simple formula, given a solution $(X,Y),$ is
$$  (X,Y) \mapsto \; \;  (T X + (T^2-1)Y, \; \; X + T Y). $$

This also leads to simple relations in just $X$ or just $Y,$ as
$$ X_{n+2} = 2T X_{n+1} - X_n,  $$
$$ Y_{n+2} = 2T Y_{n+1} - Y_n.  $$